# How to check if VideoView contains video?

Tags: android, android-videoview

For example, if I have an update screen in which the user is required to upload a video from his device. After pressing "upload" button I want to check whether there is a video in VideoView.
This is how I check about the text:

```
newStatus.isEmpty()||newStatus.trim().isEmpty()
```

I want something similiar for the VideoView. 
Thanks!

Comment: VideoView is a display surface used to show video. There will be a video in it if you tell it to play one. You can query the current state with e.g. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#isPlaying()

Comment: As far a I know, there will be a video in it if I would use video.setVideoUri(...) for example. But it doesn't necessarily mean that there is a video running at this moment. What am I missing?

Comment: @fadden I checked the method you referred me to and unfortunately this is not what I'm looking for. It only indicates whether the video is running at this moment. Do you have any other ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try `getDuration()`. It seems to return -1 for me before I have loaded a video.